# ¿Por qué no puedo decrementar una variable dentro de un método en Java?

Tags: java, string, variables, método

**Éste sería el código para obtener el último carácter de una cadena:**

```
String object = "noun";   
int variable = object.length();  
System.out.println(object.charAt(variable-1));
```

---

Resultado en la Consola:

> n

---

**Si sabemos que:

variable-1 = variable--

¿Por qué este código da error?**

```
String object = "noun";   
int variable = object.length();  
System.out.println(object.charAt(variable--));
```

**¿Pero no éste?:**

```
String object = "noun";   
int variable = object.length();  
variable--;    
System.out.println(object.charAt(variable));
```

[image: eror]
[image: no error]

Comment: Te funciono la solución propuesta?, si es así, no olvides aceptar la respuesta, para que la pregunta no quede abierta sin responder, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Los operadores de *pre-(incremento/decremento)* (`++Varible o --Variable`) y *post-(incremento/decremento)* (`Variable++ o Variable--`) funcionan de la siguiente manera:

> - Pre-incremento: la operacion es definida en la variable antes de ser utilizada.
> - Post-incremento: la operación es definida en la variable después de ser utilizada.

Por ejemplo, digamos que tienes un arreglo de tipo `int`:

```
int[] arreglo = new int[2];
int posicion = 0;
```

Si intentas acceder a las posiciones con *post-(incremento/decremento)* ocurre lo siguiente:

```
int numero = arreglo[posicion++]; // accede a la posicion 0

// En este punto, la variable posicion ya fue alterada, por lo tanto posicion = 1
```

Si intentas acceder a las posiciones con *pre-(incremento/decremento)*, ocurre lo siguiente:

```
int numero = arreglo[++posicion]; // Accede a la posicion 1, porque pre-incremento, es decir, posicion fue alterada antes de su uso
```

La ejecución de la operación es indicada según la sentencia, por lo que si intentas hacer esto:

```
int a = 10;
int b = a--; 

//Tanto a como b equivalen a 9, a fue alterada, y b infiere en la referencia de a
```

En tu solución, deberías hacer:

```
String object="noun";
int variable=object.length();
System.out.println(object.charAt(--variable));

// A sabiendas de que en este punto variable es una unidad menor a la que tenia previo a la sentencia ejecutada
```